# ImportXML - Google Sheets but incomplete HTML

Tags: html, xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

First of all, I'm a newbie and doesn't know programming. I am trying to use importxml on one of my sheets but it doesn't work as it is always returning as an empty cell. When I view the page source of my URL, it only shows this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   <title>Management Console</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.6/lumen/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="root">
</div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCtv3S4sKtUtwBwvvkQuGbq3HrzGftdJpc&libraries=geometry"></script>
<script src="/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Whereas, when I open it using inspect on Chrome, there are more information on the line between div id="root" and /div. I am not sure if it something I can still get using xpath. Please see attached pic for what I am seeing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

IMPORTXML can only access the source code not the modified DOM by JavaScript or other by other means in contrary as a web browser does, so IMPORTXML isn't the tool the get the required value.