# IMPORTXML on Google Sheets formula error

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets, xml-parsing

How do I pull the number of followers from the following page using IMPORTXML on google sheets? You can find the number of followers right below the orange "Add to Portfolio"
https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/MITT

I have the above url in cell A1, and I'm trying to use the following formula unsuccessfully

```
=importxml($A$1,"//div[@class='followers-number']")
```

Answer (score 0):

I searched for the class name, the value and the word followers on the source code returned by the URL but they aren't there. IMPORTXML only can access the source code of the page, not content added programmatically, so IMPORTXML isn't the tool the get the required value.

Related

- [importXML Parse Error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20766174/1595451)
- [ImportXML - Google Sheets but incomplete HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40579407/1595451)